# Need regular expression that will work to find numeric and alpha characters in a string

Tags: numeric

Here's what I'm trying to do.  A user can type in a search string, which can include '*' or '?' wildcard characters.  I'm finding this works with regular strings but not with ones including numeric characters.

e.g:
414D512052524D2E535441524B2E4E45298B8751202AE908
1208

if I look for a section of that hex string, it returns false.  If I look for "120" or "208" in the "1208" string it fails.

Right now, my regular expression pattern ends up looking like this when a user enters, say "w?f": '\bw.?f\b'

I'm (obviously) not well-versed in regular expressions at the moment, but would appreciate any pointers someone may have to handle numeric characters in the way I need to - thanks!

Code in question:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param searchString
 * @param strToBeSearched
 * @return
 */
public boolean findString(String searchString, String strToBeSearched) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(wildcardToRegex(searchString));
    return pattern.matcher(strToBeSearched).find();
}

private String wildcardToRegex(String wildcard){
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(wildcard.length());
    s.append("\\b");
    for (int i = 0, is = wildcard.length(); i < is; i++) {
        char c = wildcard.charAt(i);
        switch(c) {
        case '*':
            s.append(".*");
            break;
        case '?':
            s.append(".?");
            break;
        default:
            s.append(c);
            break;
        }
    }
    s.append("\\b");
    return(s.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your string to search in is

```
1208
```

The search "term" the user enters is

```
120
```

The pattern then is

```
\b120\b
```

The `\b` (word boundary) meta-character matches **beginning** and **end** of "words".
In our example, this can't work because `120` != `1208`

The pattern has to be

```
\b.*120.*\b
```

where `.*` means `match a variable number of characters (including null)`.

**Solution:**

- either add the `.*`s to your `wildcardToRegex(...)` method to make this functionality work out-of-the-box,
- or tell your users to search for `*120*`, because your `*` wildcard character does exactly the same.
  This is, in fact, my preference because the user can then define whether to search for entries starting with something (search for `something*`), including something (`*something*`), ending with something (`*something`), or exactly something (`something`).

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to be working great in all my testing so far!